# C# Core MVC Razor Duplicate Fields AutoFill/Complete

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a page in my C# Core project (MVC using Razor Pages) that I have duplicate types of information. In this case it is a Model that contains both *delivery address information* and also *billing address information*. So my model looks like this:

```
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string BillingName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string BillingAddress1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string BillingAddress2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Town")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string BillingTown { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "County")]
    public string BillingCounty { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string BillingPostCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string DeliveryName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 1")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string DeliveryAddress1 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Address Line 2")]
    public string DeliveryAddress2 { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Town")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string DeliveryTown { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "County")]
    public string DeliveryCounty { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Required")]
    public string DeliveryPostCode { get; set; }
```

So when I render this on the page using

```
<input asp-for="BillingName " class="form-control" />
```

It renders the input fields fine and their corresponding id and name would be (in this case) `BillingName`.

```
<input class="form-control" type="text" data-val="true" data-val-required="Required" id="BillingName" name="BillingName" value="">
```

This is fine, but I need the chrome auto-fill / auto-complete to try and fill this `BillingName` with their Name. But because the field has an id and name of `BillingName`, Chrome knows nothing about this.

Is there a way to have the `id="BillingName"` and the `name="Name"`?
So I could then have another field: `id="DeliveryName"` and the `name="Name"`

But, I need the model binding to still work to the ID when the form is posted back.

Any advice please?

Thank you.

Comment: Model binding works due to name not due to id

Comment: Ah so if it works off name then I am a bit stumped as these need to be unique. Any ideas on how I can get the auto-fill / complete to work using a name attribute set to something like "BillingEmailAddress" or am I just missing the point a bit? thank you

Comment: `Harkirat singh` means  .net core will bind data with `name` attribute.For example,you need to bind `BillingName`,you can set `name="BillingName"`,bind `BillingEmailAddress`,you can set `name="BillingEmailAddress"`.